# Who discovered the Rayleigh-Taylor instability?

Tags: physics, discoveries

Who discovered the Rayleigh-Taylor instability? Was it artist David Alfaro Siquerios? Or was he the first to observe it?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit? I think it would be a good idea to at least provide some evidence to back up your suggestion that Siquerios was the first to observe it.

Comment: @Danu-http://physicscentral.com/explore/plus/accidental-painting.cfm.....Please refer this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rayleigh published his findings in 1883. Siqueiros (thus, not "Siquerios") was born in 1896. Does that answer your question?